# fail to install ubuntu14.04 on lenovo workstation p900

Tags: 14.04

I try to install ubuntu 14.04 on lenovo workstation p900,after i finish installation and restart the computer,here is the error :error 1962 no operating system found. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

### Bios/UEFI Problem

This is not a problem with Ubuntu but with your Bios. Ubuntu uses **UEFI** to boot up that machine. UEFI is a substitute for Bios and you can google why the change and judge its merits yourself.

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFJLJyVmQ-I) seems to indicate that some Lenovo machines have a default configuration named "Legacy" which is not UEFI. You will need to change this:

1. Power On Machine (or reboot)
2. Press *F2* multiple time until a menu appears.
3. Select to 'Enter Setup'
4. Go to the Tab named 'Startup' using the Arrow Keys
5. Select **CSM** and hit Enter
6. Choose **Enable**
7. Select **Boot Priority** and hit Enter
8. Choose **UEFI First**
9. Pres F10 and select 'Yes' to save settings and reboot the machine

The problem should be solved.*****

*****Your system's "Setup Menu" may be different but the problem should be the same. Since your bios is not configured to use UEFI it does not detect Ubuntu installed.

Hope this works